# Where can I find earlier versions of Greenplum docker image or vm image?

Tags: greenplum

Where can I find earlier versions of Greenplum docker image or vm image?
Anybody know it?

Thanks

Comment: What version are you looking for? and perhaps more importantly - why?

Comment: I want to do a comparison for some features in different versions.

Comment: I see. Since greenplum don't manage an official versioned docker image, you can edit the dockerfile yourself to install a different version.

Comment: @YaronIdan Oh, that is really an good idea~ thanks!

Comment: Sure, I will add it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the greenplum dockerfile to create an image with a different version can solve your problem. Good luck!